# Move all record relationships to another record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to "merge" one record into another record with all it's relationship children.

For example:

I have `vendor1` and `vendor2` which both have many relations that contain other has_many. For example a vendor has many purchase_orders and a purchase order has many ordered_items and an ordered_item has many received_items.

If I change the `vendor2`'s name to be the same as `vendor1`'s name then I want to destroy `vendor2` but move all of it's has_many to `vendor1`.

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
  def vendor_merge(main_vendor, merge_vendor)
    relationships = [
      merge_vendor.returns, merge_vendor.receiving_and_bills,
      merge_vendor.bills, merge_vendor.purchase_orders, merge_vendor.taxes,
      Check.where(payee_id: merge_vendor.id, payee_type: "Vendor"),
      JournalEntryAccount.where(payee_id: merge_vendor.id)
    ]

    relationships.each do |relationship|
      class_name = relationship.class.name
      relationship.each do |r|
        if class_name === "Check"
          r.update(payee_id: main_vendor.id)
        else
          r.update(vendor_id: main_vendor.id)
        end
        r.save
      end

      relationship.delete_all
    end

    merge_vendor.destroy
  end
```

Doing it this way gives me constraint errors because of the has_many of the has_manys and because of the has_many through: :ect...

Any straight forward solution to this?

Comment: What constraint issues are you running into?

Comment: You said are going to change `vendor2`'s name to be same as `vendor1`'s name, but then you're also going to remove `vendor2` right? So you don't need to change the name anymore, as it will be removed anyway. Furthermore, I assumed this is what you were referring to "constraint issues": that you have uniqueness constraint for the column "name".

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario the name change equal to `vendor1` is the condition to trigger the "merge"

Comment: Do you have a uniqueness constraint on the vendor name? Could you show us all validations in your Vendor model?

Comment: @moveson the constraint has to do with the purchased_items that belong to a purchase. The name has no part in the issue.

Comment: Does the method I proposed below work? If so, great. If not, then we'll need to know more about the constraints, so we'll need to see the validations on the `Purchase` model and/or the `PurchasedItem` model.

Comment: @moveson What I wrote was an example of what I wanted to accomplish. I updated the question to my actual situation for better clarity.

Comment: @FutoRicky I recommend you to not use `delete_all` as it won't trigger callbacks. You may not have after/before destroy callbacks yet, but if you do  add one some day, this code will skip those callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a merge logic defined in your app. This could be a PORO (plain old ruby object), like `VendorMerger`, which holds all the logic in order to merge a `Vendor` record into another (this could also be inside the `Vendor` model but it would pollute your model).

Here is an example of that PORO:

```
# lib/vendor_merger.rb
class VendorMerger
  def initialize(vendor_from, vendor_to)
    @vendor_from = vendor_from
    @vendor_to = vendor_to
  end

  def perform!
    validate_before_merge!
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do # will rollback if an error is raised in this block
      migrate_related_records!
      destroy_after_merge!
    end
  end

  private

  def validate_before_merge!
    raise ArgumentError, 'Trying to merge the same record' if @vendor_from == @vendor_to
    raise ArgumentError, 'A vendor is not persisted' if @vendor_from.new_record? || @vendor_to.new_record?
    # ...
  end

  def migrate_related_records!
    # see my thought (1) below
    @vendor_from.purchases.each do |purchase|
      purchase.vendor = @vendor_to
      # ...
      purchase.save!
    end
  end

  def destroy_after_merge!
    @vendor_from.reload.destroy!
  end
```

Usage:

```
VendorMerger.new(Vendor.first, Vendor.last).perform!
```

This PORO allows you to contain all the logic related to the merge into one file. It respects the SRP (Single responsibility principle) and makes the testing very easy, as well as maintenance (ex: include a Logger, custom Error objects, etc).

**Thought (1)**: You can either go by manually retrieving the data to be merged (as in my example), but this means if some day you add another relation to the `Vendor` model, let's say `Vendor` `has_many :customers` but forgot to add it to the VendorMerger, then it will "fail silently" since VendorMerger is not aware of the new relation `:customers`. To solve this, you can dynamically grab all models having a reference to `Vendor` (where column is `vendor_id` OR the `class_name` option is equal to `'Vendor'` OR the relation is polymorphic and the `XX_type` column holds a `'Vendor'` value) and convert all those foreign from the old to the new ID.

Comment: I like this in concept better than my own solution, as it isolates responsibility for this task in a single-responsibility interactor class. But I don't understand why `migrate_related_records!` isn't just a single line: `@vendor_to.purchases << @vendor_from.purchases`. Why not do it the Rails way?

Comment: What I wrote was an example of what I wanted to accomplish. I updated the question to my actual situation for better clarity.

Comment: @moveson the exact way to shift records from a parent to another may vary depending on the preferences. The way I chose is also a "rails way", it's just exhaustive in my example to show OP can do some extra logic on each `Purchase` record, like validation or deletion.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Going to test it out, will let you know the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I disagree. The reason Rails provides relationship helpers in its models is so we don't have to worry about what id goes with what table, and instead we can think about the relationships in human terms: This vendor's purchases should move into that other vendor's purchases. I see no reason to use four lines of code to accomplish what one line of clear and understandable code can do.

Comment: Also, you are missing an `end` at the end of your class.

Comment: @moveson I provide examples, snippets of code to help OP find a way to build a stable and flexible solution. I am not providing an answer that OP can just copy-paste and forget about it right after. There is a `end` missing and probably other things that could be improved. About the way I changed the foreign of records, I don't really care about how OP will actually do it. I just want to show him that he can do some extra logic for each of those `Purchase` record. I don't really understand why you are arguing about 1% of the code that depends on the dev preferences...

Comment: I found that the whole issue was due to a `before_update` I had for `purchase_order`.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Understood, but why, when someone suggests a superior way of doing the same thing, do you not just modify the code to adopt it? I've already agreed your solution is better in concept. I'm just trying to improve the overall solution and promote using a Rails helper instead of rolling your own, particularly when the Rails helper does exactly the same thing your code does.

Comment: Your way of doing will not be raising an error if something fails (validation / callbacks) while transferring the `purchase` records from one vendor to another. This is an example of "silent fail" that takes hours to debug. Using a simple shebang version of `save` (or `update_attributes`) avoid this kind of silent fail. If there was a "shebang version of `<<`" then yes I would 100% agree that we could use it.

Comment: Actually, it's not working because after the vendor is deleted it still destroys the has_many relationships even though they where saved with the updated vendor_id.

Comment: @FutoRicky use the `reload` method on `@vendor_from` before calling `destroy`

Comment: I have deleted my answer in deference to the superior answer of @MrYoshiji. I had advocated for use of `@vendor_to.purchases << @vendor_from.purchases`, but it turns out this does not allow for solid error handling, and it also doesn't run callbacks.